# Serial voting should not be reversed when the questions/answers themselves are serial posts

Tags: feature-request, serial-voting

Yesterday, I downvoted (and flagged) 5 answers that I stumbled upon in *tools/new-answers-old-questions*. I did not single out this user, I simply went through the list of answers.

The system detected this as serial voting and reversed the votes, not taking into the account that the 5 identical answers were posted in a timeframe of 6 minutes.

Can the system be made a bit smarter for cases like this one?

Comment: Well that is what creates the frustration, when crap gets created faster than you can handle it. So I would say for now you just have to watch out that this doesn't happen to often, otherwise it will turn bad for you and you maybe get suspended for irregular voting.

Comment: related at MSE: [Fix serial downvoting reversal to not apply to users spamming site front page with bad answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199418/165773)

Comment: If see these kinds of patterns, it might pay to raise a moderator flag explaining the situation.

Comment: Just yesterday I was handling a series of flags from someone who thought it was ok to bulk-flag their own answers for moderator attention asking for votes. If I had obliged them and downvoted them all for being low quality, that would have been my first vote reversal ever. In the end, I had to abstain. So fret not - 10k users aren't the only ones with this problem.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I do raise moderator flags when it's a problem on a larger scale, but felt that it wasn't appropriate here. Their queues are long enough as it is :)

Comment: @Stijn I'm surprised you were caught by the script. It has happened a few times that I've seen users decide that they'd "spam" a tag with low quality answers to see what sticks. I've usually been able to just downvote them without having to worry about the script. These are answers I could naturally come across as I go down the questions associated with the tag, in order of most recent activity.

Comment: @Stijn I wouldn't flag a users post if he posts many VLQ posts, otherwise you will get more frustrated, because you will get a declined flag.

Comment: @JesseSielaff: Occasionally, users flag for truly idiotic reasons. This user wanted mods to (up)vote their posts, but apparently did not actually specify that. Had BoltClock actually voted, the votes would all have been downvotes, and all justified; therefore it's not only 10kers, but mods, that can have trouble with serial vote reversal for legitimate votes.

Comment: @bolt A custom flag asking for moderators to *vote* on their posts?! Surely you could have out-sourced the effort to your fellow mods. That type of cry for attention should not go unheeded.