# Why were my flags on these posts declined, when the moderator took the suggested action?

Tags: discussion, support, declined-flags

I flagged two identical answers ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666739/on-ios-7-uisearchbar-left-align-placeholder-text/35703043#35703043), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24525155/how-to-keep-the-uisearchbars-placeholder-left-aligned/35703002#35703002)) with custom flags, reporting them as duplicates of [a third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19289406/uisearchbar-search-icon-isnot-left-aligned-in-ios7/35702982#35702982).

I do this frequently enough that I have a canned comment (based on Martijn's) that I typically leave:

> Please do not post [duplicate answers](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). Instead, tailor each of your answers to the specific question. If you have the necessary reputation points, you can [flag](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts) or [vote-to-close](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions) questions as duplicates, where appropriate.

I am reasonably sure that I placed comments on both posts, but one is gone now. (I may have missed it - that's not the worry.)

Both my flags got declined:

> **declined** - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

However, the posts were deleted by a moderator (ChrisF), with this comment added:

> Please do not post duplicate answers. Instead, tailor each of your answers to the specific question. If you have the necessary reputation points, you can flag questions as duplicates, where appropriate.

...that comment is almost identical to mine, so it doesn't appear I was thinking wrong here.

Is there a reasonable explanation why flags reporting these duplicate answers would be declined?

The community has received guidance in the past that we should flag such answers - if that is not desired, then is there some new guidance we should be following?

> If you're spotting a duplicate answer to duplicate questions, flag or vote to close and **then flag the answer on the duplicate question for removal** (leave the other one alone).
>
> <sup>Emphasis mine; quoted from the "canonical" answer to the Stack Exchange Meta FAQ question: **[Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211726/288751)**</sup>

Comment: I can't comment on why the flags were declined, but your flag text consisted solely of `duplicate - link` without any explanation of **what** you wanted the mod to do.  When flagging for a mod be specific on what you expect when they look at a flag - even something like _this user is posting the same answer on multiple questions - they should be deleted_ would be much better than what you used.

Comment: It's possible that someone else flagged the posts erroneously, and all flags were declined at once, even though your flag wasn't the cause of the problem.  I also know that automatic flags are cast for duplicate answers like this, so the message could just be, "mods are already getting an automatic flag for this, there's no point in you casting an additional flag".

Comment: @bluefeet that did not help me [here](http://i.imgur.com/cBkfyad.jpg)

Comment: To clarify bluefeet's comment further, that flag text would be very easy to mistake for someone asserting that the question should be closed as a duplicate, which isn't something you should flag a moderator for.

Comment: @bluefeet I agree that the mod flag should be detailed.  but the canned response from the mod does not help either.  Isn't mod flagging what you are supposed to do when you discover duplicate answer being posted?

Comment: @bluefeet is this a general rule? I usually just explain the problem in a mod flag, but I never try to tell the mod what to do, and consciously.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Whenever you flag something for mod attention via a custom flag - you should be as specific as possible with the problem.  Fewer details will typically lead to declines. More details the better.

Comment: @bluefeet - I've gone both ways with explanations, sometimes running out of characters. That wouldn't be a problem here, ofc. However, I've used this short form numerous times, and this would be the first time it didn't get "helpful", so _statistically speaking_ they don't tend to get declined. But yeah, I could have been wordier.

Comment: It's willy nilly. Some non-exact trick the system get declined saying our script picks it up. Even when it doesn't. So some of us won't even flag anymore. So be it.

Comment: It was obviously a dup so if anything it was helpful regardless of whether you think it should have been flagged, it was. The OP was being helpful and `[helpful]` should have been the response.

Comment: I deleted your comment (which I replaced with one of my own) because I wasn't sure whether the answerer had seen it or not and I knew they would definitely see mine even though the answer was deleted.

Comment: *Was just in the process of apologising @ChrisF when the answer was deleted*. Just wanted to say we do appreciate the job you guys do and it can't be easy but there is a worrying trend toward the negative in the SO community of late and I don't just mean declining flags.

Comment: @Lankymart - that's OK. I decided to delete the answer as it clearly wasn't helping.

Comment: For <10k Chris's answer --> http://i.stack.imgur.com/94WGT.png

Comment: I've noticed a negative stigma around having a flag declined. I used to feel bad declining flags, but I'll admit I don't anymore. There is nothing to be ashamed of for having a flag declined. No moderator is going to take you less seriously because of some declined flags. It's a tiny statistic somewhere that really isn't worth getting worked up over.

Comment: @corsiKa except that if your hobby is flagging crap posts like these, then you can very quickly get a few declined flags, enough to lead to a flag ban. That's bad for everyone.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is how I would have responded to your flags:

> helpful - fyi, answers that are exact copies will trigger automatic "duplicate answer" flags, so you don't have to flag these yourself in the future unless they are at least a few days old

Yes, moderators can mark flags as helpful *and* provide a custom message advising the user. This feature was added at least a couple of years ago on top of the ability to *decline* flags with a custom message.

The caveat is that flags are often "fire and forget", which is why helpful flags tend not to generate notifications. Now, for users who routinely check their history, this won't be a problem, but for those who have no idea the flag history exists or that *moderators even respond to custom flags*, things can get pretty awkward for everyone involved. Yet SE says this simply isn't a problem — [requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172262/add-a-notification-on-moderator-comments-on-flags) to [implement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239738/send-custom-flag-responses-to-messages-inbox) notifications for custom flag responses to both helpful and declined flags have been ignored.

I completely agree with the comments from Louis:

> The fact that automatic flags are raised is pretty damned obscure to many of us. The notion that manual flagging on top of automatic flags is downright bad is even more obscure. And the canned message we get on declined flags does absolutely nothing to educate us. We 've got a system which is set to generate frustration all around. Yay! – Louis

and Tiny Giant:

> I'm aware of many occasions when auto-flags are raised, but I'm certain I don't know all of them, and I know from experience that a great many users are not even aware of the ones that I'm aware of. You can't expect the user to know everything that you know when declining flags, because it is likely that they don't. Right now you're assuming that users are guilty until they are proven innocent. – Tiny Giant

And this is why I mark custom flags that are clearly in good faith as helpful — *with* additional information if necessary. You just hear more about the idiotic flags (as quoted from [Nathan Tuggy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317606/serial-voting-should-not-be-reversed-when-the-questions-answers-themselves-are-s#comment313276_317606)) I decline from people who [seemingly don't understand what a moderator is and what sort of situations warrant (or not) calling the police](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284338/add-another-canned-flag-decline-reason/284357#284357), but that doesn't mean I don't take helpful flags as seriously.

Note however that flags marked as helpful in this way are not a signal to users to continue flagging in the same manner (as you can tell from the message, obviously) — I can imagine starting to decline custom flags from a user who is not heeding the advice that's given to them by the same people reviewing their previous flags, if it means getting the point across.

The only (other) situation in which I may moderate a post while still declining a flag is when the post is problematic but the choice of flag is completely inappropriate, such as "wrong answer" on a post that is NAA, or "please help me" on a question that needs to be closed, not answered.

Comment: "try to err on the side of clearing as `[helpful]` whenever the user is trying to be genuinely helpful..." ([September 2011 Moderator Newsletter](http://modnewsletter.stackexchange.com/2011/09/september-2011-newsletter/))

Comment: Only decent answer here.

Comment: @gnat Agreed! Plus this - *"Users are asked to flag posts to help keep the city street clean. Even if you feel the flag was not technically correct, **you don’t want to continually send the message that their help is no longer wanted**. That is not what the feature is about."*

Comment: @gnat I remember Shog saying (or someone paraphrasing him) that since answers mod deleted are used for audits, they should only clear as "helpful" whenever it was a clear cut scenario.

Comment: @Braiam: Does that apply to custom flags? When he says audits, I think of flags like NAA/VLQ/close reasons - those definitely should be treated more strictly.

Comment: @Braiam sure, [Why are the moderators being so strict with quality related flags recently?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160755/165773) This case though looks fairly clear cut since decline only is justified with "oh but system already auto-flagged it"

Comment: @BoltClock ^^^ you forgot Spam, it also feeds audits

Comment: @gnat dully noted

Comment: @Braiam FWIW I recently reconsidered that "for audits approach" and came to conclusion that it is [wrong and harmful](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318082/839601). "audits based on flags handled by moderator are _already_ as good as it gets - because these have passed human verification by a trusted reviewer..."

Comment: How do I check my history?  I often wish I could check back on a flag to make sure I did it right, but don't know how to do that.

Comment: @Trisped your [meta-tag:flag-history] is shown to you (and to moderators) at http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/641833

Comment: @gnat Thanks.  Just so I know, is there a link somewhere for this?

Comment: @Trisped how to find link is explained at [tag wiki page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/flag-history/info)

Comment: `The caveat is that flags are often "fire and forget", which is why helpful flags tend not to generate notifications.` Am I missing something? I've *never* gotten a notification for a declined flag either

Comment: @Rob: Yeah that wasn't clear. Flags never ever generate inbox notifications. A nitpicker would say that declined flags generate warnings the next time you open the flag dialog, though that isn't nearly the same as an instant notification.

Comment: Hilariously, the answer to which the comment of mine that you quoted here is now deleted, making this whole shebang all the more confusing.

Answer (score 23):

Recently I've seen several answers from mods that boil down to: "your flags are just extra pain, stop that". Sorry, but that's not how you encourage users to help you cleanup site.

You DO NOT punish users for not being familiar with obscure mod-only background job. Regular users don't see your autoflags - they don't exist for them and it is ridiculous to order user to even be aware about them, less to know if they are raised or not just to be able to use user-side flagging feature.

**If flag is posted in good faith and matches facts (i.e. answer is indeed duplicate) it is "helpful". Period.**

If you [CBA](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cba) to handle honest input from people trying to help and rather stamp it with "go away" resolution, maybe it is time to step down from moderatorial duty - nobody forcing you to deal with it.

Now to solutions: every time I hear "it is already handled by automatic system" my first question is: why same system can't handle such flags too? I don't know how your UI looks, but as long as there is matching automatic and manual flags on content, just hide them from "manual" queue and write in "automatic queue" something like "autoflag+3 user flags" and auto-accept all when you accept automatic flag. If auto-flag is dealt in any other way, you either get choice to automatically handle them in same way or just unhide them in regular queue.

Comment: You need to bear in mind that mods are restricted as well and only have a finite number of tools to help them mod the queue. The real issues is [so] staff not providing the tools to help them better manage these scenarios. A lot of requests have been made and ignored by [so] until that stops nothing will change.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. It is STILL no reason to punish users. Once again: I worked in volunteer-based support service too in LiveJournal. You either accept hardships and continue to treat each user positively or you step down. You're not losing anything except your mod privelegies for that.

Comment: I can't argue with that, there is no reason for punishing SO users who are trying to be helpful.

Comment: *"If you CBA to handle..."* What does CBA mean?

Comment: @CodyGray ["Can't Be Arsed. Unwilling to expend energy on the task in hand."](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cba)

Comment: @CodyGray Can't Be Ars*d

Comment: By the way, you have access to the 10k Tools screen. @Lankymart doesn't due to rep. It would be easy for you to double your current Helpful Flags count in a day if you were to use it with the New Answers to Old Questions. As an aside, using a new userscript from TinyGiant with the effect seen [here](http://i.imgur.com/Zh2sFma.jpg) , one can place comments and flag directly off of that screen without much effort.

Answer (score 17):

I think [BoltClock's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317939/why-were-my-flags-on-these-posts-declined-when-mod-took-the-suggested-action/317973#317973) is pretty good advice for mods. Any time someone takes the time to type up a custom message in a flag where there's a real problem that needs mod attention, it's worth encouraging them *even if their description is lacking.*

That said, your description of the problem *was* lacking... So while I appreciate you taking the time to try and address a problem you observed, here are a few suggestions for making this more productive in the future:

1. **Make sure there's a problem first!** Believe it or not, duplicate answers aren't actually a problem. They're a pretty strong heuristic, and you usually want to check 'em out because they're common hallmarks of spammers, non-answers and/or duplicate *questions*... But when no such problem presents itself, it's not really a big deal if someone finds a way to answer multiple, distinct questions with the same text. If you don't do this, then the moderator handling the flag has to... And they may not come to the same conclusion you did.
2. **Be explicit about the problem!** That problem you identified in step 1? Make sure you state it in your flag text! Otherwise, your effort may be wasted if the moderator handling the flag doesn't see the same problem you did.

That's it, really. Instead of "Duplicate of [link]" just type "Duplicate of [link] doesn't address this question" or "Duplicate answer to duplicate question [link]" or "EVERYTHING THIS PERSON POSTS IS SPAM AND I'M OUT OF SPAM FLAGS HALP!" Doesn't have to be a novel, although the occasional limerick wouldn't go amiss.

Comment: "I opened their profile and snooped; all of their answers are dupes! I've flagged for a mod, who should get out their rod, and eliminate this pile of poop!"

Comment: On  a serious note, though - I started flagging duplicate answers because once I was a 10K user I saw many deleted questions with mod's (usually Martijn's) comment which I quoted in my question. Typically, the answers weren't spam, the questions weren't dupes... the only problem was the _existence_ of duplicate answers that didn't directly address the given question. As in the case that started this post, they were... tangential, shall we say? Not irrelevant. So - I learned by observing, and tried to help by emulating that behaviour.

Comment: WRT problem descriptions... are the comments we leave on the posts as guidance to users NOT part of the problem description? For example, a NAA flag can mean many things - so I leave a comment on the answer most of the time to clarify my POV, as I did in this case.

Comment: The comments are good. The problem is that the mod handling the flag doesn't necessarily see the comment until after they've already been investigating the situation for a bit; the comment isn't tied to the flag, it's tied to the post. That second comment you left *here* - where you say "the existence of duplicate answers that didn't directly address the given question" - that's a pretty damn useful summary of the problem right there. You could put that in the flag and it'd be a really useful flag.

Comment: Now you tell me, limericks are the way to get things done around here. Good to know.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to flag duplicate answers unless they are at least a few days old. There are already automatic flags in place to alert moderators to duplicate answers, so your flags are actually redundant, and can end up causing extra work (because you flagged the *other* post in the pair, for example).

The moderator declined those flags for that reason; trying to let you know you don't have to seek out and flag stuff here.

Yes, we post comments to try and correct the user behaviour (stop them from copying and pasting duplicate answers), but that's *not the same thing as flagging*. Custom flags go to the moderators, comments to the answerer.

Or did you perhaps misunderstand the comments I leave on such duplicates? I ask the *answerer* to use flags to mark duplicate *questions*, rather than copy and paste their answers. I am not asking others to flag duplicate *answers*.

I've gone ahead and [clarified this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/211726/revisions) in the [canonical FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions/211726#211726).

Comment: So then we should get rid of all the post out there that say you should flag duplicate answers?

Comment: @NathanOliver: where do I say you should flag duplicate answers. I want the *answerer* to flag duplicate *questions*.

Comment: [The canonical reference post on meta encourages flagging such answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211726/288751). Note that Nathan said "the post out there that say you should flag" not "the post out there where you say that we should flag". As far as I can tell he is not implying that you specifically have encouraged that, but that the behavior *is* encouraged. There is guidance all over meta.SO and meta.SE saying these should be flagged.

Comment: You can add value in flags still (e.g. telling us this is the third account doing the same), or poking around domains/companies that the duplicated posts link to and proving a connection. It's also worth noting that the automatic flag isn't magic: if the posts are different enough they don't get auto-flagged, but can still be duplicate answers. But the exact copy and paste case with just one user doing all the posts is already automatically handled.

Comment: @Flexo: OK, so you are saying that the canonical reference post on Stack Exchange Meta is incorrect? Note that the author is animuson.

Comment: So the rule is if an auto flagged would be raised do not mod flag?  Are we supposed to remember all of the auto flag rules?  Why can't I just flag it when I see it and not have to remember which bad stuff I do not have to flag?  I do not agree with declining a flag simply because it was auto flagged so you didn't need to flag it.  It was auto flagged because it was bad enough that it needs to be handled.

Comment: @TinyGiant - the flag or vote toe close on the question is definitely useful, (as a mod that's a really hard call to make) but if you want to flag an answer and have it be useful you need to say *more* than the automatic flag that the linked post points out is raised.

Comment: @TinyGiant: thanks, I've updated those posts.

Comment: The fact that automatic flags are raised is pretty damned obscure to many of us. The notion that manual flagging on top of automatic flags is downright bad is even more obscure. And the canned message we get on declined flags does absolutely nothing to educate us. We 've got a system which is set to generate frustration all around. Yay!

Comment: @Louis: there may be a case for improved canned messages, but take into account we handle **hundreds** of flags a day. I've handled nearly 500 so far and the day isn't over yet. We can't customise every decline.

Comment: I honestly don't see the harm in marking the flags as helpful, or at least declining the flag with a link to a meta post saying they shouldn't be flagged. I understand that you process lots of flags in a day, but is it really that difficult to let the user know why those posts shouldn't be flagged?

Comment: @TinyGiant: We'll have to wait for Chris to come back; I don't know how many flags he was processing at the time. But really, if we spent as much time on flags as we do on discussing this, the queue would be unmanageable.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That is not right.  If *The moderator declined those flags for that reason; trying to let you know you don't have to seek out and flag stuff here.* then he should let you know.  Just using *flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention* does nothing but waste a bunch of peoples time since we have to make a meta to get to the bottom of it.  A simple *no need to flag as copy paste answers are auto flagged* would work.

Comment: No one is asking that  have a meta post about every flag you handle, but simply asking that you write "Exact duplicate answers raise auto flags, no need to flag these" for these flags only, or something similarly educational in the decline reason. Using the canned "That post didn't need our attention, stop wasting my time" (paraphrased) decline reason is definitely not helpful.

Comment: @TinyGiant - In general, I mark these as helpful. Back when the 10k tools were active and displayed duplicate posts that were flagged for this, we did have a number of people who tried to farm helpful flags by piggybacking flags on these. I'd decline with a custom message in cases like that to get people to stop taking advantage of these facilities. We have had a few cases recently where people mass-flagged posts like this in response to queries, so I've declined those with custom flags.

Comment: @Brad: Great. I can understand a declined flag on such content if I receive a custom message explaining why I shouldn't flag such content. I am opposed to these flags being declined with the stock "It doesn't need our attention" reason.

Comment: Thanks for updating the canonical, Martijn - that improves it as a helpful link in comments I (we) leave for users posting highly-similar answers.

Comment: @TinyGiant I put in a feature request for more/better mod decline messages previously: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284338/add-another-canned-flag-decline-reason#comment146645_284338

Comment: Okay, so feature request: if a user flags something that the automatic mechanism also flags, why not just let the system mark the user's flag helpful automatically too? No need to bother mods with it, and the user would also not be punished for trying to help.

Comment: @Jester: that's open to abuse. Find auto flag reasons and flag your way to a badge.

Comment: @Jester: and that feature would hide legitimate flag reasons where you try to alert moderators to a *different* issue.

Comment: I'm mildly disturbed by recent amount of mod's answer to different questions that sum not to "we did it to improve site", but to "we don't want your flags and actively work to discourage them".

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov: where do we say that? We are saying: there's a lot of flags, cut us a little slack while we process them all. We are working on ways to make this better, including cutting out the horrendous noise some members of the community produce.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, because that's verbatim what I see in answers: don't give us your flags, they're extra pain. And declining is inherently negative too. There's lots of other things that could be done instead - like sort flags that match auto-flags to down of your mod tool and auto-accept all of them when action is done on any of them or whatever. Telling users "you are only allowed to help if you follow some strict, but hidden and obscure rules" and punishing them for not doing so is far from the best way to encourage them.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov: Then ask for better transparency in flagging from the developers! Don't go putting words into moderators mouths here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, was it me who put "decline" into moderator's mouth?

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov: where did I imply that? I am talking about your [comment from 20 minutes ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317939/why-were-my-flags-on-these-posts-declined-when-mod-took-the-suggested-action/317942?noredirect=1#comment315401_317942).

Comment: @MartijnPieters, was it me who put "your flags are actually redundant, and can end up causing extra work" in your mouth?

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov: So I can't explain why I think another moderator declined a flag? That's not the same thing as "we don't wan't your flags and actively work to discourage them". That's a *very broad brush* you are applying there.

Answer (score -2):

Here is my take.

1) The mods are too busy to handle this. This includes, fairly, that they have lives, like to shop for food, eat it on ocassion, and go to kid's soccer games. And other innocent pursuits.

2) The organization and the mods want you to rely on the [Borg's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jm8Uj.jpg) super duper scripts to spot and handle this on their behalf. When that fails, they are hoping for #3 below. Read: [Pass the buck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_passing) . Brace yourself, because you are not going to like #3.

3) Throw yourself in the middle of moderation activity until they show up. Even if that means chasing people around and appear as a stalker and serial downvoter. Even if you are not, and all the similar posts are all obviously stacked on top of each other in the timeline on the 10K Tools screen. This plebian mod activitiy includes all the the back and forth time-suck with the poster. All of which can range from helpful/educational, to outright hostilities.

Answer: So that is why it got rejected. You weren't engaging in #3. And there was your flag, when the mod's kid's soccer game was over.

Which is precisely why I refuse to flag those particular ones, or do #3. Been there, no thanks.

Comment: For the record: no, number 3 is not helpful. We don't need flags like this, for the reasons explained in Martijn's and ChrisF's answers, but being a stalker or serial downvoter just causes *more* problems for us to clean up.

Comment: I understand the sentiment, Drew, I do. There are parts of community moderation that I habitually avoid due to the high PITA factor. Flagging may be my next ceased activity.

Comment: It gets tiring being asked "why are you looking into this user" when in reality it is all stacked and visible on the same screen. And SO built the screen.

Comment: And @EdCottrell , mods are giving guidance to DV and leave comments. So then I agree with you. Don't DV and don't leave comments. Just let the Borg scripts figure it out.

Comment: @Drew Appropriate DVs and comments are great. Stalking and serial DVing, not so much. (Serial DVs get reversed, anyway.) We already deal with duplicate answers, and we almost always catch it when the people who posted them are posting other garbage as well. There's no need for users to run it all down for us. And you'd be surprised how much moderator time gets spent dealing with people who are chasing each other all over the site (and the larger network).

Comment: The second we touch it with a comment, we are married to the moderation. I will let the next set of willing and able people take that on. That campaign usually does not last long for anyone.

Comment: The whole idea of this site is that it's community moderated. That's what makes it work. Every high-reputation member who casts a close vote, downvote, or votes to delete a post has already "thrown themselves into the middle of moderation". The ideal state would be that elected moderators would only need to act on [a handful of situations](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251177/19679), with normal members being able to deal with the rest, but we're not there yet. The majority of flags on this site are already being handled by the community, not moderators, without any stalking being involved.

Comment: I believe most of us would agree that flags are highly unwanted by the mods (more work orders) and rejected flags and bans are unwanted by the users casting them. Flags are anonymous. All the votes you just described are anonymous. The only way a poster gets educated is with a comment trail and someone owning that moderation. That is not too anonymous. Not too many people are stepping up for that.

Comment: Several of us in [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) are involved in that effort. It dilutes the other moderation we are involved in. Perhaps a separate room and a comment to go there for lengthy discussion could be useful. Unfortunately, new users lack the rep to even to go to chat and speak.

Comment: @Drew - It's incorrect to assume that flags are highly unwanted by moderators. We greatly appreciate flags that let us know about things the community could not handle. When we decline flags, it's not out of anger or irritation at the flagger, it's an attempt to educate and direct flagging away from items that might not need it. Moderators volunteered for this, and I know I feel like I'm making a positive difference when I act on the many useful flags that come in every day. Again, the end goal is for every flag that comes in to be something new that only a moderator could handle.

Comment: I agree. Any education on this matter presented by Mogsdad, the first line of contact, appears to be in our hands. That is work we are happy to do and do, do. Attempting to figure out with peer recommendations how that can sanely happen. Because the current system is burning people out. And that means they stop.