# How long should a mod wait before reviewing flags for the low quality queue to give enough time to allow the community review?

Tags: support, declined-flags, low-quality-posts, moderators

I've gotten a sharp increase in [declined flags](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/3956566?group=1&status=3) recently.

I flagged the following as NAA:

The first two were flagged and declined within 9 hours, the remainder within 19 hours.

[Expandable RecyclerView with Grid Layout Manager as child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639111/expandable-recyclerview-with-grid-layout-manager-as-child/35970147#35970147)

[Image and text alignment in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969210/image-and-text-alignment-in-webview/35969271#35969271)

[Android Studio layout way off on different devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942049/android-studio-layout-way-off-on-different-devices/35966090#35966090)

[react-router Link doesn't render href attribute with server side rendering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35959965/react-router-link-doesnt-render-href-attribute-with-server-side-rendering/35966923#35966923)

[How to render an xls with formulas already rendered in fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35887832/how-to-render-an-xls-with-formulas-already-rendered-in-fields/35967264#35967264)

None of the answers have upvotes or are the accepted answer, triggers that will place them in the mod queue. The low quality review queue is now under 500, but has been sitting over 500 for the past few days, which to me means it takes some time for the community to review the posts. I have found that the community does delete many posts of the quality that I have linked here.

I have 1156 helpful flags and now 39 declined flags (13 of which are in the last 8 days)

I was under the impression that mods were to mainly handle flags that the community could not.
Is it reasonable for a mod to come in and decline my flags without giving the community time to review my flags?

*This is not a discussion, but a support question wanting a factual response from an authority, not opinions from community members.*

47 declined flags now, if the mods hurry, there's another 13 waiting for review.

Comment: Note that the ~500 posts in LQP includes posts added by the quality heuristics, not just posts flagged by users, so it's hard to use that to judge how quickly the community processes flags.

Comment: Also, if you're looking for a factual response from the mods, maybe the title should be "How long _do_ mods wait..." instead of "How long _should_..."?  The latter seems to invite debate.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I've noticed it can take a day or two for the rep reversal on downvotes for posts flagged.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom they used to wait longer to decline flags, it's now quicker, I don't want to know how long they do wait, but if they are supposed to wait and give the community a chance and if so, how long.

Comment: It takes an either an hour or 24 hours for stuff from the review queue to pop into the mod queue; so you've got at least an hour to resolve it.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker it seems there's a discrepancy with what individual mods think is low qual and the community, despite much of the discussion on meta, arguing semantics, the community has a low tolerance to low qual answers on the site.

Comment: Please stop flagging every answer that is short and includes a link. You are not doing anyone any favors.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't think crappy answers which say, yeh you can do this x with y and here's a link how to have a place on SO. I think we need to delete crap off the site.

Comment: What kind of answers are you looking for? When someone asks "how can I do x" and someone replies with "you can do x with y, here's a link to how", that is a perfectly valid answer. If it really bothers you, edit a summary of the information from the link into the answer.

Comment: @CodyGray answers where the poster of the answer goes to the bother of providing a decent answer or none at all. Is it so much to ask? I don't like crappy answers with little effort. And you are criticising me for wanting a better effort. It's bizarre.

Comment: I realise that making a push against crappy posts here is like making a push in WWI, it never achieves anything. Oops my bad I forgot. I'll leave the debate and can flag as I see fit, just as people can review those flags as they see fit.

Comment: All of the answers that you've referenced in your post are actually answers, and none of them have severe content or formatting problems. They are probably all worthy of either downvotes or editing respectively, but none of them are worth flagging.

Comment: No, I am criticizing you for requesting the deletion of things that actually provide an answer to the question. I have pretty high quality standards. I'm not advocating the acceptance of crap. But these answers just don't fall below that threshold. Granted, I don't know enough about the subject matter to know if they are *correct* answers or not. Maybe that is the problem. Maybe you're an Android expert, and you look at these and say that the answers are wrong. But if that's the case, you should downvote. Don't flag as LQ or NAA because they *are* answers. Deletion is inappropriate.

Comment: It looks to me like you are behaving as a machine algorithm would. You see a short answer with a link, and you assume that it is not an answer. But if that were all that were required, we could just have a machine automatically delete these. Or refuse to accept them from the outset. But that isn't a solution. There are questions that can be answered in only a few words, with a supplemental link to the documentation. It boggles my mind how you legitimately think there is anything wrong with that.

Comment: Please see: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/288751). You shouldn't be flagging things hoping that they are reviewed incorrectly in the LQPRQ, you should be operating under the assumption that a moderator will review all of your flags.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't flag all of them, I flag the ones I don't believe add value to this site. Simple. Yes the android one, was like saying water is wet, put in xml layouts for different size screens, anyone can know that, doing it is far more complicated. I swear I could answer a lot of questions if I was going to answer like that, but I am aware it does next to nothing to help the OP and could be useful as a comment with a link. Also don't presume to know my intention, or attack me personally.  I am an intelligent sentient being and meta too often degenerates into personal insults.

Comment: If something fit within the criteria for the flags available to you, it means that it should not be flagged. Crap answers, if they are *attempts* to answer the question, do not have *severe* content or formatting problems, should not be flagged with the NaA or VLQ flags. They may warrant downvotes, and possibly delete voted from users that have delete votes if those users deem them to be delete worthy. If you want to get rid of worthless crap on the site that doesn't fit within the defined flagging criteria, you should get to 20k rep and start casting delete votes.

Comment: Again, you should not be flagging something hoping that your flags will be handled incorrectly by users in the LQPRQ. If you're doing that, then you're part of the problem. You should always assume that your flags will be reviewed by a moderator whenever you flag something.

Comment: I also want to include: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue) (stolen from @TinyGiant)

Comment: It has a clear question and a clear answer, how can it not be seeking input and discussion?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I declined most (if not all) of these. George did a great job of explaining *why*, I have nothing to add there.

---

To answer your question:

Flags drop into the moderator queue after an hour or two anyway. I can delete, or decline, a *lot* of flags in the time it takes the community to handle one or two in review. That's helpful to the community.

**If a moderator would decline your flag, you shouldn't flag**. If the community is deleting things that a moderator would decline flags on, we've got a problem - either with the community or with the moderator. If the problem is with me, I'm receptive to feedback.

Where your flag is handled should be irrelevant. If it makes a difference, we have a problem.

Comment: Thanks, that is a clear explanation. Except I think George's answer was like pulling teeth if you go through the edit history.

Comment: There is a discrepancy between results reviewed by the community and mods, mods are stricter, but that's outside of the scope of the question.

Comment: "I can delete, or decline, a lot of flags in the time it takes the community to handle one or two in review." -- You seem to think that's a good thing.  I think it indicates a problem.  Just as we don't need diamonds handling "thank you" comment flags, we don't need them handling "thank you" answer flags either.  VLQ/NAA decisions should be easy, so they should be handled by the community, leaving the mods to handle other things.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom this may make an interesting lead on discussion question from this? :D

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom - I'd love to see these be completely offloaded to the community, but at present [they are generated far faster than the community can handle them](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318039/19679). Why that is can be debated. Should we remove heuristically-identified posts from the Low Quality review queue? Should "not an answer" and "very low quality" flags be split into separate review queues? Should the "very low quality" flag be removed entirely? I don't know what the best solution is for driving more of this to the community.

Comment: @BradLarson I think the very low quality flag should be removed and the NAA flag broadened in scope, as I believe that the community would like to see a lot of content off the site that currently doesn't fit either of these flags as they stand. My tens cents and of course it's open to debate.

Comment: Good to see you have stepped right up, and are doing a great job! Indeed, the notion that the community might have deleted these answers without a moderator's intervention is quite concerning to me. The flagging of anything with a link is getting quite out of hand.

Comment: I think a clarification could be made here that voting to delete crap answers if a user has delete votes is good, whereas recommending them for deletion in the LQPRQ is a bad thing if they are technically attempts to answer questions, and they don't have severe content or formatting problems. Otherwise, great answer, and I love the good work you're doing. Now if we could just get some of those robo-reviewers review banned...

Comment: This all sounds a lot like a consequence of the recent vogue of punishing answerers for posting to bad questions.  The OP has advocated this strategy to try to improve Q+A quality before.  Trying to marshal the review queues or moderators to pursue this strategy is certainly doomed to fail.  Of course it is.  I fear what's going to happen next, this is likely to be substituted with chat room raiding parties, Tiny leading the rampage.  SE really, *really* needs to fix the Close Vote review queue so it becomes meaningful again.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not advocating punishing anyone, just deleting crap off the site. You have a problem with that? Do you really think that the linked answers brought any value to the site?

Comment: I most certainly have a big problem with that, I find your strategy absolutely abhorrent.  This site has always applied the one-man-one-vote way of judging content and relied on answerers to make the content useful.  It has been *very* successful doing this and you are seriously undermining the underpinnings of that success.  That's what I think, message delivered, I doubt it will sway you.

Comment: @HansPassant how am I undermining the one-man-one-vote? That is not a logical leap.

Comment: I told you this before, use your own vote to judge content.  If you see an answer you don't like then just DV it, done.  And for crissake, look at the question first, bad questions invariably beget poor answers.  That problem started at the Q, not the A.  Don't also flag it to get more people to see it your way.

Comment: @HansPassant But then what's the point of having votes to delete posts? You just think leave it there and let the up and downvotes sort it out? So my obsession with deleting content is misguided, just learn to live with it.

Comment: Afaict you don't have any votes to delete posts.  Not enough rep so you are not trusted enough yet to do it right.  It prevents misguided people from damaging the site, that was thought through carefully as well.  You'll have to learn to live with it.

Comment: @HansPassant and I am wondering what you think is wrong with the close vote queue. I'm not being funny, I'm listening to you (for once).

Comment: It contains entirely too much irrelevant junk, the kind that makes reviewers give up because it is a waste of time.  Close votes are only really effective if they are cast within an hour or less from the time the question gets posted.  I think SE keeps it artificially inflated, less complaints that way, but the alternatives SO users are reaching for are definitely worse.

Comment: @TinyGiant: Would you mind elaborating on that distinction [in my M.SE question on the subject](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269877/when-should-i-vote-to-delete-answers-that-i-wouldnt-flag)?

Comment: @FrankerZ We're human too. Handling hard, time consuming flags all day - while possibly more *efficient* - sometimes isn't as rewarding as handling a hundred easier flags. And sometimes I just don't have time to suss out a voting ring, or I'm on mobile, or any number of factors. There are more than a thousand 'other' flags right now on SO - don't worry, yours won't get lost.

Answer (score 23):

> I was under the impression that mods were to mainly handle flags that the community could not. Is it reasonable for a mod to come in and decline my flags without giving the community time to review my flags?

**Absolutely**. Your flagging was bad and if a moderator didn't stop it, it'd do more damage by rippling through the system.

Your main complaint is a moderator declined these flags without giving the community a chance to accept them.

> it seems there's a discrepancy with what individual mods think is low qual and the community, despite much of the discussion on meta, arguing semantics, the community has a low tolerance to low qual answers on the site. -  [Ms Yvette ǝʇʇǝʌʎ sW](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3956566/ms-yvette-%c7%9d%ca%87%ca%87%c7%9d%ca%8c%ca%8e-sw) 16 mins ago

In this case, had the community 'accepted' these flags and the users were informed their answers were deleted because they were "not an answer", we would have had a problem on our hands.

**All of these flags were rightly declined and the system sent the correct message by letting a moderator decline them**.

If your hope was that the community would accept the flags; that would cause more problems for us down the lane.

Finally, all your flags were rightly declined because they were incorrect flags (and none of those posts should have been flagged; they should be downvoted).

- [Expandable RecyclerView with Grid Layout Manager as child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639111/expandable-recyclerview-with-grid-layout-manager-as-child/35970147#35970147):

> You can use Expandable RecyclerVew and for children view use other RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager
>
> https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view

Declined because it is an answer.

- [Image and text alignment in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969210/image-and-text-alignment-in-webview/35969271#35969271)

> You can use some CSS rules like `vertical-align` or maybe `float: left;`
>
> -> http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

Again, declined because it is an answer.

- [Android studio layout way off on different devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942049/android-studio-layout-way-off-on-different-devices/35966090#35966090)

> Unfortunately,only using dp as dimensions won't help you much.
>
> Creating different layout files for different screen sizes is the solution.
>
> Please read the link below. it contains all the information you need.
>
> http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Once again, declined because it is an answer.

- [react-router Link doesn't render href attribute with server side rendering?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35966923/16587)

> Please consult the React Router server rendering guide: 
>   https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ServerRendering.md
>
> You need to render your components in an appropriate routing context
>   for `<Link>` to generate URLs.

Yet again, declined because it is an answer.

- [How to render an xls with formulas already rendered in fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35887832/how-to-render-an-xls-with-formulas-already-rendered-in-fields/35967264#35967264)

> I needed to append a .value to the end to get the value out.
>
> Details on the fix here: https://github.com/autotelik/datashift_spree/issues/56

Finally, declined because it is an answer.

You seem to be swimming upstream. All of these can stand on their own as answers. They're not "link only" (if that term really has any meaning) because they all impart information outside of the link that can be used to answer the question. They *might* be "low quality", although I dispute that for a number of those answers; but *none* of them are "very low quality", which is the bar a moderator would have to use to delete them.

None of these answers meet the criteria for the "Not an answer" flag.

Comment: I said I flagged them as NAA, don't NAAs end up in the low qual queue? And you have not answered my question at all, you have side stepped it. Technically this is NAA.

Comment: Hm I wonder if my flag will be declined.

Comment: @MsYvetteǝʇʇǝʌʎsW I would decline your flag; but I shouldn't handle flags on my own posts. Sooo....

Comment: You still haven't answered my question.

Comment: @MsYvetteǝʇʇǝʌʎsW Sure I did. You asked "I was under the impression that mods were to mainly handle flags that the community could not. Is it reasonable for a mod to come in and decline my flags without giving the community time to review my flags?" To which I answered: In this case? Absolutely. Your flagging was bad and if a moderator didn't stop it, it'd do more damage by rippling through the system.

Comment: @MsYvetteǝʇʇǝʌʎsW If you think this answer is NAA-flag-worthy, then this is perhaps the problem/confusion you're having. If an answer has information in the body itself which could potentially serve as an answer, then it's an answer. It may be a wrong, crap, dangerous, or nonsensical, but that doesn't make it "not an answer". If you ask me "what time is it?" and I answer with "26:05", then I have given you a wrong and somewhat nonsensical answer. Yet, I have given you an answer. This is downvote-worthy, but not for removal as "not an answer". Just because you don't like it doesn't make it NAA.

Comment: *How long should a mod wait before reviewing flags for the low quality queue to give enough time to allow the community review?*

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I see what you mean, but there are plenty  of posts like that in the queue that are deleted. As much as the rules are dictated, the community also has it's own mind :D

Comment: @MsYvetteǝʇʇǝʌʎsW If that's your only question, then this question is a duplicate. Right now it's set to an hour. You have at least 1 hour to get the community to adjudicate your flags before we do.

Comment: The question was asking if there was a protocol with the timimg. But apparently there is not. One mods opinion differs from the community. I doubt if these questions were deleted it would damage the system. Do we really need.. Oh you can do this and here's a link type answers? It's a bit dramatic to infer I've missed the mark by so much when I have over 1000 flags approved and reviewed over 2000 posts from the low qual queue. I'm representative of what the community values and being worthwhile on the site. Not what we're 'supposed' to accept as ok for the site.

Comment: @MsYvetteǝʇʇǝʌʎsW You know for all the "I'm not asking about these declined flags" you're doing; every comment you make asks about those declined flags and why they're declined.

Comment: `"I'm representative of what the community values and being worthwhile on the site"` -> I'm sorry, but I find this a rather arrogant statement. I, for one, have done roughly an equal amount of reviews, and do *not* agree with you here! How do you know that your particular opinion is representative? Did you do a poll?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker don't turn it into a personal slinging match calling me arrogant. I mean representative to have 1000 helpful flags, there must be some accord with the community, just as you have. Whether we agree or not, we are representative of the community. The community has varying opinions and users, we do not agree on all things, the point is we must be in accord with a significant proportion of the community or we wouldn't have helpful flags. etc yada yada.

Comment: Whatever George, my whole point is, if the community reviewed it, there was an increased chance of them being approved, as the mods reviews and communities vary, but this is a discussion for another post.

Comment: Well there's always a chance you'll get some robo-reviewers in the community queue, there are somewhat fewer robo-reviewers among the moderators.

Comment: @RobertLongson somewhat fewer :-)