# Insight into auto-flags on posts (and possibly generic spam/VLQ/NAA flags) for 10k users

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderator-abilities

Recently, I witnessed a rollback war on a question in which the user repeatedly was trying to deface his post mocking people for downvoting his answer. Shortly thereafter, I was inclined to flag the post as "Needs moderator attention", but after a discussion in the SOCVR room, it appears that these rollback wars get auto-flagged (see [this post](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121948/what-triggers-the-possible-rollback-war-flag)).

After some further discussion, I thought it would be useful for the higher reputation users to get some insights into the auto flag (and moreover possibly the generic spam/VLQ/NAA flags) to help with cleanup using their delete votes.

Some of the main talking points:

[@NathanOliver](//chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/33612612#33612612):

> For me it makes no difference but I can see why it would be helpful. especially since some mods decline flags because they were already handled by an auto flag

[@Tunaki](//chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/33612650#33612650):

> Ah. Showing a small blurb to >10k or something that "A system flag has automatically been raised, there is no need to raise one again" would be nice indeed. But... there are a lot of corner cases here.

Personally, I think it would reduce the number of reports to moderators, which would make their lives a bit easier, as well as allow some of the 10k/20k users to help remove problematic posts which break the rules of the site. What do you think?

Comment: ChrisF beat you to the punch: There's a faq post about auto-flags that are raised now! http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317987/what-flags-are-automatically-raised-by-the-system Okay, granted, you'd have to think to look for that and it wouldn't be automatic. But it is still helpful.

Comment: @Kendra See my reply to this [here](//chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/33612582#33612582)

Comment: @Kendra And also: Some of the flags are vague. For example "If post exceeds N characters". What is *N*?

Comment: Mods should (hopefully) not be declining flags because there was an auto flag on it. See [Why were my flags on these posts declined, when the moderator took the suggested action?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317973/2581872). If they are, that's something that they should change.

Comment: @hichris123 Still another flag that they would need to look at/determine if it's helpful. Even if it's only a few seconds, it's still something that takes time away from a moderator.

Comment: No, you can mark all flags on a post as helpful.

Answer (score 7):

Custom flags can still have value when added on top of system-generated flags. A custom flag added onto something that's already generated a system flag will sort that flagged item higher in the flag queue (generally, anything with two flags on it will jump to the front of the queue). That can help identify items we need to look at right then, and separate those out from the unsorted pile of custom flags or noisy system-generated ones.

In general, we've only rejected custom flags added onto system-generated ones for things that aren't all that urgent and don't need the added attention. The few cases that I remember are:

- flags about a post being excessively long
- people using custom flags to indicate things of low quality
- flags about people duplicating answers

The system-generated or standard flags are perfectly fine in each of those cases.

Beyond that, if someone is getting into a heated rollback war, you're fine to flag about that (particularly if the user starts spouting obscenities, as they did in the case you mention). That's something that could use immediate attention. Likewise for clear ragequits (that the "possible vandalism: deletions" and "possible vandalism: deletions" auto-flags are pretty bad at pointing out) and very heated arguments in comments (to add onto the "too many comments" auto-flag).

In the cases where a moderator really, really needs to step in, don't worry about whether or not another flag has been raised on this.

Comment: One of the things @hichris123 mentioned was that as moderators you can mark all the flags as helpful on the post. Do you usually do this in these cases, where you take action on the post? Does this slow down the process at all, or is this off-set by the value that custom flags add value to system-generated ones?

Comment: @FrankerZ - Yup, by default all flags are accepted or declined as one in a single action. It was only a couple years ago that we got the ability to accept or decline each flag separately, and even then it's more work to do so than to handle them all as one unit. When we decline flags added onto system-generated ones it's more to indicate that boosting the priority of a meh item isn't warranted (like duplicate but good answers, which we'll get to eventually).

Comment: Define 'duplicate' but good answers. What if they're different by one letter, or even a punctuation mark? Does the system trigger in this case? This is where I think the transparency of a "This has already been flagged" would be a case for: "I don't want to be declined.". Perhaps in these cases, it would be fruitful to add a message (Like @Tunaki mentioned)

Comment: @FrankerZ: Good idea - I'll keep that in mind next time I handle flags of this nature.