# Can questions which are job offers be flagged using custom flags, or should we use only spam flags, or maybe not flag them at all?

Tags: discussion, flags, spam

Note: I am NOT asking [Are job offers spam?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276249) since I already agree that it is. This question is more about how to properly handle such questions as my custom-flags was rejected.

---

I recently saw a question which IMO is only a job offer. This is its entire content:

> I am looking to hire a tutor to build a simple relational database maybe a couple of tables. I have been using low-code programs for years and really want to learn the nuts and bolts. I would love to be able to hose a website for users and manage the back end. I have limited knowledge of programming. I understand the concepts. I have taken a couple of semesters of programming in school including Python, Java, C++.

Aside from delete-voting I flagged it using *custom flag* with message:

> It is a job offer, not a question.

which IMO can be interpreted as SPAM flag + reasons why I think that way
(I sometimes use custom flags for SPAM since from my experience moderators not always interpret SPAM word same way I do which sometimes lead to declining them. Since `SPAM` flag doesn't have text-area for clarification/explanation this is only way to add it).

To my surprise this flag was declined with message:

> declined - Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see [What is Flagging?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)

**How should I interpret that decision and replay?**

What is confusing me:

- does it encourage me to use *standard* flags over *custom* flags (like "spam")?

  But if that is the case, then moderator handling my flag probably realizes that there is some *other* flag which can be applied here. That would mean he sees *some* problem which can be correctly flagged for moderation, but to my surprise flagged question still stays without any change (it is not deleted, locked, edited) so that is probably not it.
- Then maybe I shouldn't flag such posts at all? (but why, shouldn't spam be flagged?)
- OR maybe was it moderator's mistake?

**What is the official procedure in case of this kind of job-offer-questions (for users like me)?**

Comment: Spam. There's a post covering this elsewhere either here or on MSE that I'm too lazy to dig up.

Comment: Duplicate (I am not able to flag it as duplicate): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276249/are-job-offers-spam

Comment: @Damien Not exactly a duplicate. I already saw [Are job offers spam?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276249) question and know that *community* agrees that this is a spam, but what I am interested in is *official* information about *how to handle* that kind of questions since as described in post my custom-flag was *declined*.

Comment: I guess the moderator wanted to let you know that you should use standard flags for such cases in the future and only custom flag if there's really a need to explain why it's spam (e. g. if it isn't obviously spam but you know more).

Comment: What seems most surprising is not that your custom flag was rejected, assuming a spam flag is better, but the fact that the question was not immediately closed then, as you mentioned yourself

Comment: Related: [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58032/269301) "A post should be marked as spam only if it advertises a product, service, or similar and is unsolicited or lacks disclosure."

Comment: @Damien "*What seems most surprising is not that your custom flag was rejected*" and I am since if I recall correctly one of moderators few years ago expressed that point of flags is to let moderation know that there is post with *something* which require their attention, category of flag helps to locate that thing, but if moderator is able to still determine the problem then regardless of used category of flat it was *helpful* for community. Maybe that idea no longer applies to spam/rude flags as they have their own systems which based on flag counts can delete posts automatically.

Comment: @nbk "Does this answer your question" no see explanation in my comment directly above yours.

Comment: @Pshemo what do you expect for another answer, it is clear off topic as stated in the link provided

Comment: Just for the record, mods tend to decline flags that can be handled by regular flags for precisely that reason - preventing you from assuming mod flags is the right action to take. It could probably have been handled better and included a message saying "please flag as spam instead as per <policy>", but meh. Flagging as spam is the right action to take here - the mod flag being  declined doesn't mean it's the wrong action

Comment: @nbk As stated in title, I would like to get some explanation about why custom-flag is not correct way to handle this kind of question (or maybe it is, and my case was mistake).

Comment: Spam is a good choice(which i use),, because it deletes automatically after 3 or so flags, offtopic is also ok because it is offtpic

Comment: @Zoe "*the mod flag being declined doesn't mean it's the wrong action*" that is something new to me, and if that is really true then I am not sure I want to have anything to do with flagging system which I don't understand...

Comment: Yeah, that sentence was horribly phrased. Happens some times :') I meant that the mod flag being declined doesn't mean flagging as spam is the wrong action. Sorry about that

Comment: I just flagged that question as SPAM this time. Will see how this experiment goes :)

Comment: Always when you are unsure downvote it, that attracts attention

Comment: @Pshemo Aw, come on, this again? Yeah, I agree: if mod is declining flags to teach "those stupid users" to not give them too much load, why not simply step down and free yourself? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317939/why-were-my-flags-on-these-posts-declined-when-the-moderator-took-the-suggested/

Comment: Aaaand its gone: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63564888/tutor-to-build-a-simple-relational-database-using-java-or-js-mysql-php-admin-w). Experiment went well, SPAM flag worked as intended.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to raise a custom flag just to explain why you think that it's spam - just link to the canonical Meta post in the comments and flag as spam - that way other people who look at the post will understand why you're flagging it. You can also post a [flag-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flag-pls) request in the [SOCVR chatroom](https://socvr.org/) if you'd like more people to look at it.

In general, it's much better to raise standard flags where possible. Other people have pointed this out, but the community can deal with trolling and spam on its own because if enough people flag as spam or rude/abusive it'll automatically be deleted.

That's another reason you shouldn't flag for moderator intervention - in general, you should only "bug" moderators to do stuff that the community can't do itself. Deleting spam and trolling, removing VLQ answers, closing off-topic questions, etc. can generally be done by the community. Mod flags are for stuff like voting fraud (because the community can't hand out suspensions or invalidate votes). Just by way of example, I recently encountered a case where the OP admitted to being 12, which is below the minimum age where someone's allowed to have a SO account; I flagged for moderator intervention because there's no way for me to clean up accounts as an "ordinary" community member (which is what site policy requires in cases like that for legal reasons).

Comment: "*Deleting spam and trolling, removing VLQ answers, closing off-topic questions, etc. can generally be done by the community.*" usually that is the case, but what about posts which community missed? Post which is subject of my question had `-4` score but none deletion votes nor was it flagged as SPAM as much since its content was not blocked. There was no change within next hour which is why I decided to ping moderators.

Comment: But your answer gives me another (and probably better for all) alternative which is [`SOCVR chatroom`](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). While it may not *official* way how company designed to handle such situations, it is definitely how *community* may handle it itself and will become my default choice from now on for such situations.

Comment: @Pshemo For trolling and spam, there's also Smoke Detector (run by the Charcoal group) that gets it in front of a lot of people as well.

Answer (score 5):

> What is the official procedure in case of this kind of job-offer-questions (for users like me)?

Downvote, flag as spam, and move on.

---

> (I sometimes use custom flags for SPAM since from my experience moderators not always interpret SPAM word same way I do which sometimes lead to declining them.).

<strike>Diamond moderators don't deal with spam flags.</strike> Apparently they do, see comments.

My original answer was based on [the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) for this topic. However based on the discussion below, it seems the page doesn't reflect how spam flags are handled in practice. According to the comments:

- Moderators see spam flags at the top of their list.
- Moderators generally deal with spam flags when they see them.

If a moderator interprets spam differently, it's not likely that an explanation will help. But more importantly, custom flags force moderators to take time to deal with something that could be handled by the system. As pointed out in EJoshuaS's answer, the SOCVR chat room has a [flag-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flag-pls) tag for this.

Comment: "*Diamond moderators don't see spam flags*" are you sure? I have one span flag declined with information: "`Apr 26 '14 at 14:04   declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it`". Or maybe word `moderator` in that message refers to "algorithm" and not *human* moderator?

Comment: I'm actually not sure what would cause spam flags to be seen by a moderator. The help page says `Moderators may step in to handle flags that aren't handled by ordinary members of the site or the system`, but it also says that spam flags are handled by the system. I think it's safe to say that it's very rare for moderators to see spam flags. It may be that the owner of that post flagged it for moderator intervention because they disagreed with your spam flag, but I don't have a way to verify that.

Comment: `Diamond moderators don't deal with spam flags.` We do, actually. They show up at the top of our list.

Comment: Spam flags age away after 4 days, not 48 hours, IIRC. I'd have to double-check the ones of mine which have aged away. I'm not aware of spam flags every aging away on SO, but it does happen from time to time on small sites where the moderators are not that active. The last I checked, I have 18 spam or R/A flags that have aged away on other sites.

Comment: Huh, then the help page is both out of date and a little misleading. What do moderators usually do with spam flags?

Comment: We can cast our own binding flag (instant close/delete by Community and -100 rep penalty), we can delete the post (automatic helpful for all flags) or we can decline them.

Comment: Do you usually take that action, or do you usually let the system handle it? If the former, then the help page is just plain wrong.

Comment: @JoshuaWade I'd expect moderators to almost always act on the spam/R/A flags when they see them (seeing them requires a page refresh). In most cases, moderators are not here to sit on our hands, particularly not for cases which are fairly clear-cut, as most spam and R/A usually is. OTOH, we may take some time to do investigation for things that are not *obvious*.

Comment: In some cases, obvious spam/rude is handled by the Community directly. And some comments are automatically deleted upon a flag being raised. But most tend to be outstanding and red flags show up first in the list of flags. SO tends to carry very few outstanding red flags that I've seen

Comment: Based on looking at a couple of the R/A flags I've raised which have aged away: spam and R/A flags are marked "aged away" at the first run of a script at 03:00Z when the flag is > 4 days old. This means that spam and R/A flags will age away when they are between 4 and 5 days old at 03:00Z.

Comment: @Makyen Good 'ol mod tooling says this in the console under Details 
"Posts flagged as rude or abusive or spam do not necessarily require action!

If any post reaches 6 flags, it is automatically removed from the system.

Flags will automatically and harmlessly age away after 4 days if they fail to reach the threshold in that time."