# System falsely identifying votes as Serial Downvotes

Tags: bug, serial-voting

Here's an odd case I encountered this morning regarding the system detecting serial downvoting.

Here's a link to the post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39584993/an-excel-macro-to-automatically-number-and-indent-vba-code

The issue here is that this question, along with all five of its answers, are from the same user.  The question has since been put on-hold.  I'll leave the judging for whether or not these should be downvoted up to personal opinion.

*However*, I did downvote the question and each of the answers (and from the looks of it this morning, several other people have done the same thing).

Fast forward to this morning, and all of the downvotes that the user received on the answers were reversed, and handled as they were a serial downvote, as in this one question, all six of posts were done by the same user.

I'm not sure how the system would identify it differently, but this seems like a bug.  Voting (whether up or down) on multiple answers by the same user on the same question should not automatically be flagged as serial voting.

Comment: Related: [Serial voting should not be reversed when the questions/answers themselves are serial posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317606/serial-voting-should-not-be-reversed-when-the-questions-answers-themselves-are-s)

Comment: I think a custom mod flag would have been better. Looks like the user tries to use that SO page as a combination of a blog and a code repository... a self-answer that turns into a complete GitHub entry. Well meant but off-topic.

Comment: Well, you found the edge case.  I suppose that's something.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You downvoted 5 answers by the *same* user, in a couple of seconds.

That's the *definition* of serial downvoting. The system doesn't care if the answers are all on the same question.

It's not a bug, it's a feature.

That said, I was able to delete-vote the question and its answers. With the [attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect) this question got, it was deleted in no time.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing that the meets the definition, but if they're all separate answers on the same question by the same user, that kinda makes it difficult to vote either way on their content.

Comment: @Siyual The system is not perfect but the few cases where this is needed does not out weigh all of the cases where people do this as a form of punishment.

Comment: How common is this exact situation?  Seems pretty rare to need special handling by the script (making it more complex and more prone to bad reversals or missed cases of actual serial voting).