# Are system algorithms smart enough to differentiate organic downvotes and malicious ones?

Tags: discussion

Over the last few days while I've been stalking the new questions category for the Android tag I have down-voted or flagged a lot of bad questions and guessed answers.

More than once though I've recognized that I've down-voted posts from the same few usernames 2 or 3 times in a row (obviously because they happen to be the same people active at the same time as me).

I want to know if I am safe in down-voting these posts or whether I should just ignore the bad content when I recognize I've taken action on another of their posts, to avoid having my voting/flagging privileges frozen or reversed because the system thinks I am targeting a user

Will the system recognize that these are all new questions and real votes? (I do often add comments with these votes, if that affects anything)

Note: Once I finished writing this question, [this other question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317606/serial-voting-should-not-be-reversed-when-the-questions-answers-themselves-are-s) popped up in the 'Similar Questions' box which is likely related - I don't think this is duplicate - his question relates to old questions which I imagine might have very different heuristics from newly added ones (also it has no actual answers)

Comment: It depends but if you're not finding those posts by opening their userprofile and then down vote everything you see, you should be fine.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Only SE employees can tell you the specifics of this, and they probably won't, but I can comment on general trends I've noticed.

The automatic serial downvote script is very conservative in what it invalidates. You have to have given a large number of downvotes to one person within a very short period of time for it to trigger. Manual vote invalidation by an SE employee (usually in response to a moderator request) is of course a different story.

I see no indication of any vote invalidation between you and any person you may have voted against multiple times. In general, if there's any kind of natural spacing between your votes, they don't get invalidated. Unless an employee wants to share more specifics (again, they probably won't), that's about the best I can tell you.

Comment: Thanks, I have no idea if I'll even know if votes get reversed, but I thought it was probably worth a check! With regards to flags - many of them result in closed questions, but sometimes not enough people also vote to close (despite them downvoting) which means I'll have a lot of unverified flags - can this hurt me?

Comment: @NickCardoso - Pending close flags? If they age away, it's as if they were never cast. They don't hurt you in any way.

Comment: @NickCardoso close flags? Shouldn't you just be voting to close, not flagging?

Comment: Yes I was voting to close, I mis-used the term flag

Comment: It's probably obvious, but it may be worth mentioning that the *reason*, in case anyone asks, why employees don't share these specifics is to maintain the security and integrity of the automatic process; if people knew the triggers, they would know exactly when to stop to avoid detection.